# Looping Matlab data to excel in different columns

Tags: excel, matlab

I would like to know how to rearrange these obtained values from Simulink to a more appropriate format so that plotting can be done easily.

The raw data obtained from simulink is shown below:

val(:,:,1) =

```
1.2500
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
2.5000
```

val(:,:,2) =

```
1.2500
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
7.5000
```

However, what I wish is in the format as shown below:

```
1.2500      1.2500
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000 
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
2.5000      7.5000
```

I have tried looping code as below:

Index_c = 10;

for c = 1:Index_c

```
y = simout.signals.values(:,:,c) %Simulink data

xlswrite('testdata.xls', y, ['A' num2str(c)])
```

end

but this is copying all to different sheets and what I want is just copying them to different columns. Is there anyone who can help me on this? It really doesn't matter copying the data to excel or to a new variable in Matlab. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does anyone know how to do this in excel,i.e., sending data array by array from Matlab to excel in different columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think [squeeze](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html) can pull this one off:

```
squeeze(val)
```

it removes the singleton dimensions; so if those rows you have in your post, are the only one in `val`, the result should be a Nx2 matrix.

Comment: Gunther, thank you so much! This is exactly what I am looking for. How silly am I thinking of doing it in more complicated way! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I consider this reshaping the data:

```
>> reshaped_val = reshape(val, [], 2)
```

Comment: I can't really reshape the data due to the existance of "val(:,:,1) = and val(:,:,2) =" in the raw data variable.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you just said. I have edited my post to show that the `reshape` function doesn't modify val, and you can save the reshaped data to another variable.

Comment: @kit: what do you mean by that? performing the above ^^ just as well removes the singleton dimension from a Nx1x2 matrix

Comment: Oh, yeah. It could. Actually I was reading the help file on reshape command and the example didn't show the word val. Also I didn't think of my variable is actually is a 2X1 matrix, I thought the "val(:,:,1) =" is a string which need to be removed. Now I understand what the "val(:,:,1) =" really means. Thank you guys!

Comment: However, my post has got only 2x1 matrix, if it was a large amount of data, I would need to know the dimension if using reshape command. When I use squeeze command, I simply did it without knowing the dimension. Anyway, it's good learning...

Comment: By the way, what does singleton means?

Comment: Read the documentation more closely. Singleton refers to when a dimension has length one. Like a 150x1x2 variable has a singleton dimension (the middle one). I use `[]` because I don't know how many rows there will be, but I know there will be two columns.

Comment: Cool. Seems like I am not familiar with the commands, hence explanations. What's the best way to familiarize these commands and using them freely? Learning from books won't be that useful right?